# How to write update Query in sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
update validInfo 
 set Infodesc='Animal Name',
     infodesc2='Nom d'animaux'
where infoCode=17;
```

I have an issue regarding this update query. Here my query uses  `Infodesc='Animal Name',infodesc2='Nom d'animaux'` where `Infodesc` holds an English string and `infodesc2` holds French. When I include a single quote `'` in the value it doesn't update.

How can write `infodesc2='Nom d'animaux'` so it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update validInfo 
    set Infodesc='Animal Name'
       ,infodesc2='Nom d''animaux' 
where infoCode=17;
```

When you have a single quote in your string you need to use `two single quotes` i.e (Two single quotes not a double quote) to be parsed as one string

```
merry's house      will be           'merry''s house'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the basics of programming, you need to escape the string like `'Nom d\'animaux'`

```
update validInfo 
set Infodesc='Animal Name',
infodesc2='Nom d\'animaux' 
where infoCode=17;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use double quotes instead of single quotes. For example

```
update validInfo 
set Infodesc="Animal Name"
   ,infodesc2="Nom d'animaux" 
where infoCode=17;
```

Comment: That is not true in Oracle SQL.